# How to add action to SneakyButtonSkinnedBase? (COCOS2d)

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

in one of my layer i have this button. now how can i add action on this button like jump,run etc?

```
SneakyButtonSkinnedBase *jumpbuttonBase=[SneakyButtonSkinnedBase new];    

jumpbuttonBase.position=jumpButtonPosition;

jumpbuttonBase.defaultSprite=[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"jumpUp.png"];

jumpbuttonBase.activatedSprite=[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"jumpDown.png"];

jumpbuttonBase.pressSprite=[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"jumpDown.png"];

jumpbuttonBase.button=[[SneakyButton alloc]initWithRect:jumpButtonDimensions]; 

jumpButton=[jumpbuttonBase.button retain];

jumpButton.isToggleable=NO;    

[self addChild:jumpbuttonBase];
```

Answer (score 0):

In your layer that you added the button to, have an update scheduled.

```
[self scheduleUpdate];
```

In the update method is where you check if the button has been pressed, and then you decide what action you want to perform.

```
-(void) update:(ccTime) delta
{
   if (jumpButton.active)
   {
      // do something here
   }
}
```